Does it matter what we choose to be $m$ for Schur's theorem
Below is an application of Ramsey number
Schur's theorem. For every $k \geq 1$ there is an integer $m$ such that every $k$-colouring of $[m]$ contains integers $x$, $y$, and $z$ of the same colour such that $x + y = z$.
One of the proof goes as
Proof. We claim that we can choose $m = R_k(3) - 1$. Let $n = R_k(3) = m + 1$ and let $c : [m] \to [k]$ be a $k$-colouring. This induces a $k$-edge-colouring $c'$ of the complete graph with vertex set $[n]$, as follows. For $(i, j) \in E(K_n)$, set $$c'(i, j) = c(|i - j|).$$ By the definition of $n = R_k(3)$, there is a monochromatic triangle, say with vertex set $\{h, i, j\}$, so that $1 \leq h < i < j \leq n$ and $c'(h, i) = c'(i, j) = c'(j, h)$. But then $x = i - h$, $y = j - i$, and $z = j - h$ are such that $c(x) = c(y) = c(z)$ and $x + y = z$.
My question is whether I can choose $m=R_k(3)$. I use $k$ colors to color $[m]$, now if I define the edge coloring of $K_m$ the same way as above. The only difference is now I color $K_m$ maybe less color than before (maybe do not use $c(m)$), but it seems does not matter.

Well since the theorem holds for $m= R_k(3)-1$ it will hold for any $m'\ge m$ as well, since any $k$-coloring of $[m']$ induces a $k$-coloring on $[m]$, I would say. hope that answers your question
